# Send notification to the user when he logs in from another device/location

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to add the feature in my website that user will get notified whenever its account is open in different device/location. I am using codeigniter.

Please suggest me an option for it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a suggestion. I can help you but in kind of a simple and lengthy method. What you can do is that you can make a column in your user database with the name of "IP" then when a user logs in the ip will be stored, when the user logs in again, the php will match the ip with the ip in the database. If its the same good to go! but if its not you can  redirect him to another page where he should verify his identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ion_auth in codeigniter for login purpose. It already stores the ip address of the user or login attempts if any.
What you can do is check at every login if the ip address is same as the previous one used to login , if it is send a notification.

You can also maintain a separate table if you wish to store multiple ip addresses of a single user.

Answer (score 0):

use FCM for notify the user once he login from another ip address.

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive
```